# Why openCV cv2.LUT() throws assertion if both Source image and LUT seems to be compatible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, opencv

I am experiencing some issues to be able to apply a LUT to images using openCV(4.0.0) in python 3.6.5

Starting with a LUT (look up table) of 256 elements as indicated in the documentation, and trying to apply it to a 'one line source image' (since more complex images were giving me issues as well), always produces an assertion error regarding the channels not being compatible, not being continuous, or not being the correct datatype (8 bits).

But all seems to be correct when printing the vectors information, dimensions and channels, datatype, and I guess (but I don't know how to check in python) continuity to be fine too.

Any idea why I am not able to apply the LUT?

I created a custom function to print arrays information 'print_2Darray_Info()' in order to check the shape, datatype, mean and Max/Min values.

_______  CODE  _________

```
customColorPalette = numpy.asarray([(255,255,255), ... , ( 255,150,0)],dtype=numpy.uint8)

testIMG = numpy.asarray([(1,1,1), ... ,( 255,255,0)],dtype=numpy.uint8)

print_2Darray_Info(customColorPalette,"customColorPalette")

print_2Darray_Info(test001,"test001")

cv2.LUT(arr8C3,customColorPalette)
```

_______  OUTPUT  _________

```
Array info for 'customColorPalette' ==> shape:  (256, 3)  Mean:  186.94661458333334  datatype:  <class 'numpy.uint8'>  Max and Min:  255 0
Array info for 'test001' ==> shape:  (256, 3)  Mean:  183.97005208333334  datatype:  <class 'numpy.uint8'>  Max and Min:  255 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-192-aff71f46c372> in <module>
     11 print_2Darray_Info(customColorPalette,"customColorPalette")
     12 print_2Darray_Info(test001,"test001")
---> 13 cv2.LUT(testIMG,customColorPalette)

error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\lut.cpp:368: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (lutcn == cn || lutcn == 1) && _lut.total() == 256 && _lut.isContinuous() && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_8S) in function 'cv::LUT'
```

I have tried to apply the LUT to images with these shapes and get the same error:
shape:  (120, 160, 3) 
shape:  (120, 160)
shape:  (120, 3)
shape:  (256, 3)

I expected the assertion to be success and get the LUT applied to the src image.

Comment: I think I found the solution, it is syntax related.

Definition the LUT as: `customColorPalette = numpy.asarray([[(255,255,255), ... , ( 255,150,0)]],dtype=numpy.uint8)` will solve the issue.

Notice that it requires extra square Brackets, which changes the shape of the matrix to (1, 256, 3), but seems to be the only way I found to be able to apply it on my images.